# Mongoose FindOne returns all children

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is it ok that findOne returns all subdocument in array? I mean isn't it take a long time to execute that, or is there way to get document with only one subDoc ?

my code :

```
userModel
     .find({
          {_id: userId,},
          { contacts: { $elemMatch: { userId: contactId } } }
     ).select('name contacts');
```

I cant use **userModel.contacts.id()** cause I don't have id

How can I add a conversation id to this found document
How can I do

```
const userData = userModel.findById(userId)
         .where('contacts')
         .elemMatch({ userId: contactId })
```

and get the result with only one contact (in order not to search for a contact from the entire array)

and simply change relation like

```
userData.contacts[0].conversation = conversationId;
await userData.save()
```

Comment: your way is working projecting only first matching subDoc , to return more then one matching subDocs  you can use aggregation->$filter

Comment: @R2D2 then I can not change and save the document, is not it? Also  where aggregation process happens inside app or db?

Comment: aggregation happen inside the mongoDB , if you want to change(update) the document you can easily do via update/arrayFilters option without the need to fetch whole document and store it back again ...

Comment: @R2D2 please provide an example

Comment: add some example document and let me know what need to be changed ?

Comment: @R2D2 I have edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
db.collection.update({
 _id: 1
 },
  {
    $set: {
     "contacts.$[x].conversation": 3
   }
 },
{
 arrayFilters: [
{
  "x.userId": "John"
  }
 ]
})
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n4FKTbTe8iU)